# How to make windows delete all new files on shutdown

Tags: windows-7

I've already seen this behavior in some computers like in schools and universities. It basically removes all the changes you make to the computer afer you turn it on and restores it to the exact same point it was before you started using it. I would like to know wether windows can be configured to do this or if an external program is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though I don't believe [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/638740/windows-7-boot-from-read-only-disk) is a duplicate, I posted [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/638745/201262) there about [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/). It's what most colleges, universities use in their test labs, as well as many business working in test environments.

> Deep Freeze, by Faronics, is an application available for the Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, and SUSE Linux operating systems which allows system administrators to protect the core operating system and configuration files on a workstation or server by restoring a computer back to its original configuration each time the computer restarts.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned Deep Freeze does this. (There are some others, but Deep Freeze is the most well known and most reliable software for this.)

There are 2 other options that give a similar end result but by different means:

- Don't run a real install but a Virtual Machine. Reset this to a snapshot made on startup.
- Use imaging software (like Acronis TrueImage) to restore to machine to the startup situation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no setting to accomplish this.

The computers in schools and universities were likely using either [Faronics' Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/) or [Microsoft's SteadyState](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState) (discontinued)

Comment: Steadystate can still be done, it is no longer a product though. Technet I believe has a How to Steady State on Windows 7 with mandatory profiles.